# Setting up VLAN on new Meraki Switch

Tags: vlan

Hi we have DellForce10 switches and we are changing them to Cisco Meraki switches. On the Dell switch we have the following Vlan setup:

```
Covington-CustomerCheckout-S25>show vlan

Codes: * - Default VLAN, G - GVRP VLANs, P - Primary, C - Community, I - Isolated
Q: U - Untagged, T - Tagged
   x - Dot1x untagged, X - Dot1x tagged
   G - GVRP tagged, M - Vlan-stack

    NUM    Status    Description                     Q Ports

    1      Active                                    T Po1(Gi 0/21-22)

                                                    U Gi 0/9
    102    Active    Wireless                        T Po1(Gi 0/21-22)
                                                     U Gi 0/18,20
    105    Active    DHCP_Clients                    T Po1(Gi 0/21-22)
                                                     U Gi 0/1-8,10,12-17,19
    106    Active    Static_Clients                  T Po1(Gi 0/21-22)
    109    Active    Production                      T Po1(Gi 0/21-22)
    110    Active    VOIP                            T Po1(Gi 0/21-22)
    112    Active    Management                      T Po1(Gi 0/21-22)
    220    Active    Printers                        T Po1(Gi 0/21-22)
                                                     U Gi 0/11
    999    Inactive
```

Now, the Meraki switch has Native and allowed VLANS and I am not sure how to set it up.  Below are the options that I have to set it up with. I am also a little confused on what the untagged and tagged traffic means on the the Dell switch and how that would translate onto the configuration of the Meraki Switch.

[image]
If you could please help me

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

On trunk ports, the native VLAN is untagged, and other VLANs are tagged. You are configuring a trunk port on the Cisco, according to the Type field. The native VLAN will not be tagged on the trunk, but all the other VLANs will.

No VLANs will be tagged on access ports.

It looks like the Dell has a trunk on Po1, but the other ports are access ports. It also looks like the Dell has no native VLAN set on Po1.